# Print data from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

mysql_connect("$servername", "$username", "$password") or die ("Could not connect!");
mysql_select_db("test") or die ("Could not connect to database!");

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['name'];
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalouge WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR cost LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("Could not search!");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

        if($count == 0) {
            $output = 'That item does not exist';
        }else {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $cost = $row['cost'];

                $output = '<div>Item Name: ' .$name. '<br>Cost: ' .$cost. '</div><br>';
            }
        }
    }

?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Search for an item..."></input>
    <input type="Submit" value=">>"></input>
        <?php print("$output"); ?>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I really need help in this one. I need all data to be print/echo out from the database by searching using forms. I've tried to use `print_r` and `var_dump` to try and show all the information in the database.

Comment: I've written this about twenty times today and now once more: don't use mysql_* functions anymore! Use mysqli_* or PDO, These functions are too old and they are deprecated as of PHP 7.

Comment: I was told this code is dangerous and a single sql injection can ruin everything and to use pdo or mysqli... please search for sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks perfect 
only change on this like..  you need to add dot. for concat string. next result .

```
 $output .= '<div>Item Name: ' .$name. '<br>Cost: ' .$cost. '</div><br>';
```

try it.. it will work..
its added all record in `$output` varible and only echo it after form. like this.

```
echo $output;
```

that's it.. i hope it will work for u.